# Possible automorphisms of a Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables

If we consider automorphisms of the Jacobian $J(C)$ of a curve $C$ which are compatible with the canonical polarization, we can describe this automorphism group in terms of $\text{Aut }C$ (see ``On the fields of rationality for curves and for their Jacobian varieties'' by Sekiguchi).

What is known about the structure or size of automorphism groups of Jacobians $J(C)$ which aren't necessarily compatible with the canonical polarization (possibly in relation to $\text{Aut } C$)? For example, what kinds of finite subgroups can occur inside $J(C)$?

There are previous questions related to automorphisms of $J(C)$ on MO (e.g. [endomorphisms of the Jacobian of a curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159954/endomorphisms-of-the-jacobian-of-a-curve) and [Automorphisms of Compact Riemann Surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117369/automorphisms-of-compact-riemann-surfaces)), but they seem to assume that polarizations are taken into account. Most of the papers I found seem to be related to finding Jacobians with a particular type of automorphism group, but I haven't been able to find very many on what kinds of groups are possible. One example that might be related is a paper of Anita Rojas (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmi/1190831216), but I haven't been able to find other papers related to this.